# Code for 2 ultrasonic sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, python, hc-sr04

This is my code:

```
int trigPin=13; //Sensor Trig pin connected to Arduino pin 13
int echoPin=11;  //Sensor Echo pin connected to Arduino pin 11
float pingTime;  //time for ping to travel from sensor to target and return
float targetDistance; //Distance to Target in inches
float speedOfSound=776.5; //Speed of sound in miles per hour when temp is 77 degrees.
int trigPin1=2; 
int echoPin1=3;  
float pingTime1;  //time for ping to travel from sensor to target and return 1
float targetDistance1; //Distance to Target in inches 1
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
}
 
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //Set trigger pin low
  delayMicroseconds(2000); //Let signal settle
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //Set trigPin high
  delayMicroseconds(15); //Delay in high state
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); //ping has now been sent
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Delay in low state
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW); //Set trigger pin low
  delayMicroseconds(2000); //Let signal settle
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH); //Set trigPin high
  delayMicroseconds(15); //Delay in high state
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW); //ping has now been sent
  delayMicroseconds(10); //Delay in low state
  
  pingTime1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);  //pingTime is presented in microceconds
  pingTime1=pingTime1/1000000; //convert pingTime to seconds by dividing by 1000000 (microseconds in a second)
  pingTime1=pingTime1/3600; //convert pingtime to hourse by dividing by 3600 (seconds in an hour)
  targetDistance1= speedOfSound * pingTime;  //This will be in miles, since speed of sound was miles per hour
  targetDistance1=targetDistance1/2; //Remember ping travels to target and back from target, so you must divide by 2 for actual target distance.
  targetDistance1= targetDistance*63360;    //Convert miles to inches by multipling by 63360 (inches per mile)
  pingTime = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);  //pingTime is presented in microceconds
  pingTime=pingTime/1000000; //convert pingTime to seconds by dividing by 1000000 (microseconds in a second)
  pingTime=pingTime/3600; //convert pingtime to hourse by dividing by 3600 (seconds in an hour)
  targetDistance= speedOfSound * pingTime;  //This will be in miles, since speed of sound was miles per hour
  targetDistance=targetDistance/2; //Remember ping travels to target and back from target, so you must divide by 2 for actual target distance.
  targetDistance= targetDistance*63360;    //Convert miles to inches by multipling by 63360 (inches per mile)
  
  Serial.println(targetDistance);
    
  Serial.println(targetDistance1);
  
  
  delay(100); //delay tenth of a  second to slow things down a little.
}
```

Python code:

```
import serial #Import Serial Library

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3',9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData



while (1==1):
    if (arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
        myData = arduinoSerialData.readline()
        myData=str(myData)
        myData= myData.replace("b'",'')
        myData=myData.replace("\\r\\n'",'')
        if myData<"3":

            print( myData)
```

When I compile the sketch, it shows no error.But when I run the file in python, output=0.However, when they are run individually, python gives me a valid input.so is this code correct?Also, is there a way to call for the exact c++file in python?Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1. What file you are you running in python? You didn't show your python sketch. 2. How do you distinguish between the data from the first sensor and from the second sensor? Or doesn't that matter for you?

Comment: Edit:outputs are distinguished by targetDistance1 and targetDistance(one variable has a'1' and one doesn't)

Comment: I meant it your python program. But as you are just printing every line, that doesn't really apply here. Have you checked, that the Serial output of your Arduino sketch is as you expect it to be? You could check that simply in the Serial monitor. And why are you doing `if myDATA<"3"` in your python program? Why do you only want to display lines, which are lexically at a lower order as "3"?

Comment: I was testing if my idea was gonna work..Cus the program that i am building,triggers a series of actions if distance is lesser than 3

Comment: You are not checking for the distance being lesser than 3. You first need to convert the data to a number, before you can compare it that way. Currently you are comparing two strings lexically, not 3 numbers.

Comment: Please confirm, that the Serial output is as you expected. In that case it is purely a python problem. I think you should do some basic tutorials for python and read a bit about variable types in python. That will give you enough knowledge, to write your python script correctly

Comment: Alright ill look into it from a python perspective,thanks!

Comment: I just check my python code,it just prints the data outputted by the c++ code......so is the c++ code correct?
edit:The serial output is not exactally as expected.When I run the code for each ultrasonic sensor,it gives the correct output, but when i combine them (to form the code above) the output I get is 0.00.So there is a error when i combine the 2 codes.(What i mean by individual code is the above code without the echoPin1,triggerPin1,pingTime1 ect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to measure with 2 ultrasonic sensors at once. You cannot do that so easily. You need to measure sequentially for 2 reasons:

1. The ultrasonic sensors might get confused by the others signal
2. You will miss the pulse of the one sensor, while you are reading the pulse of the other via `pulseIn()`.

So the order of actions is like this:

1. Trigger sensor 1
2. Read sensor 1 with `pulseIn()`
3. Trigger sensor 2
4. Read sensor 2 with `pulseIn()`

Comment: Thanks so much!It works perfectly!

Comment: Is there a way i can differentiate the 2 inputs?

Comment: You can print an identifier before it, for example `1:100` for the value 100 of the first sensor. Then you can split the string in python at the colon to get the sensor number and the value individually

Comment: ah okok got it thanks!!

Comment: Is it possible to add for eg "a" and "b" to differentiate the 2 values?

Comment: Sure, just Serial.print them before each corresponding value